# Cannot convert (NSError)-> Void in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8, xcode8-beta4

Hey guys so I recently updated my Xcode version to Xcode 8 and I have started getting these errors in the new betas that I haven't gotten before.

```
        CSSearchableIndex.default().indexSearchableItems([searchableItem]) { // Error.

        (error : NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Here's the error : [image]

Comment: FYI, the `Error` type is discussed briefly in the [Xcode 8 Beta Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=xcode-8-beta-rn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `NSError`, use `Error`. Or, let the compiler infer this for you.

```
CSSearchableIndex.default().indexSearchableItems([searchableItem]) { error in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: You da real mvp... I forgot NS is gone smh